# how to change content-type in rest api call from custom policies in Azure ad b2c?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to call a SMS provider through custom policies . the API provided by SMS provider accepts a JSON payload in the format mentioned below
[JSON Payload format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuNlz.png)
I am trying to call this API by passing the JOSN payload, however when I run this policy the content type in the request header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded but the API only accepts application/json.
Below is the code of the restful technical profile

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SendOtp">
          <DisplayName>Use SMS api to send the code the the user</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://japi.instaalerts.zone/httpapi/JsonReceiver</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">RequestBody</Item>
            <!-- <Item Key="DefaultUserMessageIfRequestFailed">Default</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfCircuitOpen">Not Reachable</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfDnsResolutionFailed">DNS Failed</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfRequestTimeout">Timeout</Item> -->
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="FormatOTPmsg" />
            <!-- <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="createDestArray" /> -->
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="RequestBody" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
           <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="RequestBody"/>
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Question is how to change the content type of the request ?

Comment: Do you call Graph API endpoint? I yes, could you update the question with the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the content type header, it should respect the method used to send the payload. This might be a bug, raise a MS support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to change values of headers using RestfulProvider Technical profile in B2C Custom policy. The only custom header we can add is for authentication which can be found here [B2C Restful Cryptographic keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#cryptographic-keys). It's obviously not applicable here.

I tried calling some test apis which logs headers and B2C is always sending content-type as 'application/json; charset=utf-8' while using the Meta data

```xml
<Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
```

However using Form instead of body produces the header 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

```xml
<Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Form</Item>
```

I am not able to reproduce your issue right now. This is my test api call for reference.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="TestEchoJson">
  <DisplayName>Test Echo</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">{Settings:TestApiUrl}</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
    <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">emailRequestBody</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GenerateEmailRequestBody" />
  </InputClaimsTransformations>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" />
  </InputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

You might have to raise support ticket with Microsoft if the issue persists.